# Problema con metodo POST html

Tags: html, formularios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy intentando crear un formulario y recien estoy empezando pero me da un error cuando envío el formulario e inspecciono el elemento, me da un error, quizá esta mal puesto el method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Informacion personal</legend>
        <form action="\informacionPersonal" method="post">
        
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholcer="nombre">

            <input type="submit"/>
       </form>
       </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `POST` es un método del protocolo `HTTP` ( `http://`). Vos estas ejecuntando el archivo via `File` (`file://`). Te recomiendo instalar un servidor web,

Comment: En el action estás usando una barra invertida `\ ` en lugar de una barra normal `/` que apuntaria al directorio raiz de tu dominio de tu servidor web.  Entiendo que eso lo haces dentro de un servidor web, y que ese archivo `informacionPersonal` es asp o php o algo que reconozca tu servidor web, aunque eso de que no tenga extensión, aunque posible, es preocupante y no se si sabes que sin extensión es probable que no ejecute su código interno, sea cual sea, porque los servidores web se configuran automaticamente para reconocer ciertas extensiones, sino no les pasan los handlers por seguridad.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente, el error está en la ruta del atributo `action` de la etiqueta `<form>`. El caracter "/" al inicio indica que busque en el directorio raíz `C:\` en tu caso. Si "informacionPersonal" es un archivo que está en la misma ruta que el HTML que muestras, basta con que quites el "/" al principio, pero además te falta la extensión de dicho archivo.

Comment: si entiendo, creo que lo hice mal, mi intencion era hacerlo como me dijeron, para inspeccionarlo en la parte de network sin necesidad de crear otro archivo, no sé si tiene que ver con un heather o algo así